# Determinate if a number is power of 2 but i have a problem

Tags: c#

```
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 2; i <=num; i*=2)
{
  if (i==num)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("It is power of 2");
  }
  else if (i!=num)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("It isn't power of 2");
  }
}
```

Hello, what I want to do is determine if a number is a power of 2 or not. As you have seen in the code and may recognized, the problem that comes up is, for example, if I input 16 it will output

> It isn't power of 2

> It isn't power of 2

> It isn't power of 2

> It is power of 2

Because by that, the first three values of `i` are  2, 4 and 8, and the last one 16. All said, how i do to refer to the last value of `i`

Comment: There's a simple test; Does subtracting one cause all 1's to flip to 0's. `(X & (X -1)) == 0`

Comment: Your actual problem, is that you are logging within the loop. Don't do that. Set a result flag, break out of the loop and then log.

Comment: Note that your loop does not handle negatives, and has undefined behavior if testing very large integers.  Also, from a stylistic point, you should avoid specifying the exact opposite condition in `else if`.  Here, `else` would be sufficient.

Comment: This is the perfect time for you to learn how to write a function for checking for a power of two and use it with your input.

Comment: @paddy It's C# so Convert will throw an `OverflowException`.

Comment: Oh, I thought I was viewing only C++ tags.   My bad.